# How to access tcp socket from another socket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp

I have several client connections and one should listen for data in other. How can I make a bridge between them (not an array iterator)?

Sample pseudo-code:

```
socket.on('data', function(chunk){
  decodeChunk(chunk.toString('hex'), function(response){
    if(response.name === 'toDB'){
      //write smth. to DB
    }

    if(response.name === 'readDB'){
      //watch all incoming tcp sockets with 'toDB' and continiously
      //send to client connected with this socket
    }

  });
})
```

I can use something like rabbitMQ, but it's not for current stage in order to keep development more agile.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the relevant parts of your code?

Comment: Sorry, can't share full code and that's why posted some pseudo-code. Hope it will clarify things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with such service:

```
var SocketMedium = {
  sessions: {},
  onEvent: function (event, cb) {
    if (!this.sessions[event]) {
        this.sessions[event] = [];
        this.sessions[event].push(cb);
    } else {
        this.sessions[event].push(cb);
    }

    console.log('onEvent: ', event);
  },
  rTrigger: function (event, data) {
    console.log('Started rTrigger: ', event);
    if(this.sessions[event]){
        console.log('FOUND: ', event);
        this
        .sessions[event]
        .forEach(function (cb) {
            cb(data);
        })
    }
    console.log('Completed rTrigger', this.sessions);
  },
  cleaner: function(sessionId){

    var event = 'session' + sessionId;

    if (this.sessions[event]) {
        delete this.sessions[event];
        console.log('SocketMedium cleaned: ', this.sessions[event]);
    }

    console.log('SocketMedium can not find: ', this.sessions[event]);
  } 
};

module.exports = SocketMedium;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky to address this with purely pseudo code, but I ll give it a shot anyway.

If I understand this correctly, then toDB and readDB are sample data and there are multiple toDB. Which means, you'd also have a bunch of toXY with a corresponding readXY OR a bunch of toPQ with corresponding readPQ. If so, then as soon as a toSOMETHING is connected, you can store that socket under a readSOMETHING. If the key already exists, then you d simply append the toSOMETHING socket to it. In time it would look something like this:

```
var socketData = {
    readDB: {
        sockets: [
            <socket-object-toDB-1>,
            <socket-object-toDB-2>,
            <socket-object-toDB-3>
        ]
    },
     readXY: {
        sockets: [
            <socket-object-toXY-1>,
            <socket-object-toXY-2>,
            <socket-object-toXY-3>
        ]
    }
}
```

And then your pseudo code would probably look something like

```
socket.on('data', function(chunk){
  decodeChunk(chunk.toString('hex'), function(response){
    if(response.name === 'toDB'){
      //write smth. to DB
      if (socketData['readDB']) {
        // already exists, simply append incoming socket to it's sockets array
        socketData['readDB'].sockets.push(socket);
      } else {
        // does not exist, add it with a sockets array
        socketData['readDB'] = {
          sockets: [socket]
        }
    }

    if(response.name === 'readDB'){
      // Write to all sockets of readDB
      socketData['readDB'].sockets.forEach(function(sock) {
          sock.write('Whatever message\r\n');
      });
    }

  });
})
```

Comment: It' the first idea that came to me, but I noticed "not an array iterator" to find a possible solution without such expensive method. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Another thought is to use a pub/sub model. So basically all the toSOMETHING sockets would subscribe to a custom event as soon as they connect. Then each readDB occurrence would emit that event on them. Without socketIO it would still go back to array iterators. But with socketIO maybe you can emit an event that the sockets are listening for (without using iterators).

Comment: Yep, now I try to use built-in sails.js socket.io support to handle this, but can't make it listen self-emmited messages.